# Vim: Is it possible to open multiple files and jump to specific lines?

Tags: vim, tabs

Regularly, one may open one file "foobar" and jump directly to line M as such:

```
vim +M foobar
```

Now, I have a whole list of files "foobar1", "foobar2", ..., "foobarN", all with different lines of interest M1, M2, ..., MN. Is it possible to tell Vim to open all of them in a new tab and then also jump directly to specified lines? Prototype:

```
vim -p +M1 foobar1 +M2 foobar2 ... +MN foobarN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is, e.g.

```
vim +5 foobar1 +"tabnew +6 foobar2" +"tabnew +7 foobar3"
```